# Maven: Only activate profile A if profile B is not activated?

Tags: maven, profile, activation

I have two Maven profiles profile-A and profile-B. "B" should only be activated if "A" is not activated. 
So if I would call

```
mvn install
```

profile-B is executed (but not profile-A).
But if I would call

```
mvn install -Pprofile-A
```

then only profile-A is executed (but not profile-B).

Any hints how I need to write my pom.xml to achieve this?

I already tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>profile-A</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>

  <profile>
    <id>profile-B</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      <property>
        <name>!profile-A</name>
      </property>       
      ...
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think for your example command line to work as expected, all you need is the `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>` for profile B.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html states:

> All profiles that are active by default are automatically deactivated when a profile in the POM is activated on the command line or through its activation config.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify a point that stumped me for about 15 minutes.  From the latest version of the above link regarding `activeByDefault` (emphasis mine): "This profile will automatically be active for all builds unless another profile **in the same POM** is activated using one of the previously described methods."  In my case, I had added profile B to the parent POM and profile A to a leaf POM in a multi-module build.  In this configuration, profile B was not disabled when profile A was activated via the command line.  Moving profiles A and B to the same POM produced the desired behavior.