# Activate Maven profile if another profile is not activated

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-3, maven-profiles

The question is related to [Maven: Only activate profile A if profile B is not activated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344728/maven-only-activate-profile-a-if-profile-b-is-not-activated), but it's more specific.

If I type one of the following:

```bash
mvn clean install -PspecificProfile
mvn clean install -Dsmth -PspecificProfile
mvn clean install -Dsmth -PspecificProfile,anotherProfile
```

then I want to **activate the `specificProfile`** profile. (+the additional specified profiles)

If I type anything else like:

```bash
mvn install
mvn clean install
mvn clean install -Dsmth
mvn clean install -Dsmth -PanotherProfile
mvn clean install -Dsmth -PdefaultProfile
mvn clean install -Dsmth -PdefaultProfile,anotherProfile
```

then I want to **activate the `defaultProfile`**(+the additional specified profiles).

### Idea:

```
if ( specific profile P is used via command line ) {
    activate P;
} else {
    activate the default profile;
}
activate other specified profiles;
```

### Examples:

```
mvn ...                          // default
mvn ... -PspecificProfile        // specificProfile           (no default!)
mvn ... -Px                      // default + x
mvn ... -Px,y                    // default + x + y
mvn ... -Px,specificProfile      // x + specificProfile       (no default!)
mvn ... -Px,specificProfile,y    // x + specificProfile + y   (no default!)
```

---

I tried to do something like this (in **pom.xml**):

```xml
<profile>
    <id>defaultProfile</id>
    <activation>
        <property>!x</property>
    </activation>
    ...
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>specificProfile</id>
    <properties>
        <x>true</x>
    </properties>
    ...
</profile>
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 36):

Profile x will be the the only active profile when you call `mvn ... -P x`. Reason from the maven documentation:

```
  Profiles can be explicitly specified using the -P CLI option.
  This option takes an argument that is a comma-delimited list of profile-ids to
use. When this option is specified, no profiles other than those specified in
the option argument will be activated.
```

Here's a workaround:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>!specific</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>specific</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>specific</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>x</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>x</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>y</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>y</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

The commands:

```
mvn ...                        // default
mvn ... -Dspecific             // specific Profile         (no default!)
mvn ... -Dx                    // default + x
mvn ... -Dx -Dy                // default + x + y
mvn ... -Dx -Dspecific         // x + specific Profile     (no default!)
mvn ... -Dx -Dspecific -Dy     // x + specific Profile + y (no default!)
```

Execute `mvn ... help:active-profiles` to get the list of the ids of active profiles.